# how to group by item many to many query builder laravel

Tags: laravel, join, query-builder

I have comics and categories related many to many through pivot tables. I use join and groupBy caterories.id but it doesn't group categories same comics id.

If I do not use the group

```
$result = DB::table('comics')
            ->select('comics.name','categories.title')
            ->join('category_comic', 'comics.id', '=', 'category_comic.comic_id')
            ->join('categories', 'category_comic.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->get();
```

[image: 1eb92d997625e0be4.png]

I want each comic group category

[image: 28a63202c80583d83.png]
<sub>(source: [uphinh.org](https://s1.uphinh.org/2020/05/13/28a63202c80583d83.png))</sub>

Comment: please, add more information to your question, and what you want to expect

Comment: @Kelvin i edited my question can you help me

Comment: Do you understand to use Laravel Eloquent Relationships ?, if yes you could get that response as you want

Comment: yes i can use eager loading but i want to try query builder

Comment: i already add an answer check and try it, and it is array, not a collection

Answer (score 1):

First of all
try tou use [Laravel Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) and its really cool and very easy to use

**In Eloquent Method**

In **Comics Model**

add relationship function

```
public function cat(){
     return $this->hasOne(ComicCategory::class,'id','comic_id'); //ComicCategory::class is your category_comic model
}
```

Then you just need you Comic Model to get a group of your category com

```
$result = Comic::with('cat')->get(); //Commic is your model
```

In query Builder, you need to group manual using foreach

```
$result = DB::table('comics')
            ->select('comics.name','categories.title')
            ->join('category_comic', 'comics.id', '=', 'category_comic.comic_id')
            ->join('categories', 'category_comic.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->get();

$result = json_decode(json_encode($result), TRUE);

$new_result = [];
foreach($result as $row){
     $arr[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
     $arr[$row['id']]['cat'][] = $row['title'];
}
```

and finally rearange the key

```
$new_result = array_values($new_result );
```

PS : thats array method, i never group using object method